# Neo4j - Unable to run multiple cypher files with Neo4J Docker 4.2.5

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using neo4j with docker version 4.2.5 and cypher file to initialize data.

I am setting following environment property to initialize data with docker-compose -

`NEO4J_apoc_initializer_cypher=CALL apoc.cypher.runFile ("file:///sample.cypher")`

This works fine and load the data after server started.
However, you cannot create indexes in this file. You need runSchema call to create indexes.
As per [doc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/operational/init-script/) for neo4j 4.2, you can run multiple cypher,

`NEO4J_apoc_initializer_cypher_0=CALL apoc.cypher.runSchemaFile ("file:///schema.cypher")`

`NEO4J_apoc_initializer_cypher_1=CALL apoc.cypher.runFile ("file:///sample.cypher")`

However, this throws error:

unknown settings: apoc.initilizer.cypher.0

unknown settings: apoc.initilizer.cypher.1

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. It seems the issue was the wrong documentation on how to run multiple cypher queries. Please check [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/2120) link for more details